# How to create dynamic cascade form in Symfony?

Tags: forms, symfony, dynamic, symfony-forms

I have been using Symfony 3 for a while, and until now I only generated simple forms. Now, I would like to generate a more complex, dynamic form and a bit of help would be appreciated.

My website references Products, that are associated to categories. Therefore, I created a *ProductCategory* entity which relies on the Doctrine extension *Tree*. The actual products are therefore the leaves of the tree structure, the other nodes (i.e. those with at least one child) are only product categories.

An example of such structure would be this one:

```
Food
      Fruits
           Apple
           Pear
      Vegetables
           Pepper
           Zucchini
 Vehicle
      Car
      Bike
```

In this example, the products are Apple, Pear, Pepper, Zucchini, Car and Bike.

I would like to generate a form aimed at selecting a product. The expected behavior would be this one:

- Initially, the user sees a single dropdown list with the root categories (here Food and Vehicle)
- When the user selects a category, a new dropdown appears below the previous one, populated with the subcategories corresponding to the previously selected category (e.g. Fruits and Vegetables if Food had been chosen)
- This process should be recusrive until the user selected a product, i.e. a leaf of the tree structure.

In order for the form to be valid, the user must have selected a Product (leaf).

For now, I have been able to generate the initial form with the dropdown listing the root categories. Here is the code used to do this.

```
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use AppBundle\Entity\ProductCategory;
use AppBundle\Repository\ProductCategoryRepository;
 
class ProductType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
            $builder->add('productCategory',EntityType::class,array(
                'class'         => 'AppBundle:ProductCategory',
                'query_builder' => function(ProductCategoryRepository $repository){
                        return $repository->getRootNodesQueryBuilder();
                },
                'label'         => 'product category',
                'choice_label'  => 'name',
                'choice_value'  => 'name',
                'multiple'      => false,
                'expanded'      => false,
                'required'      => true
            ));
    }
 
 
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => Product::class,
            'method' => 'POST',
        ));
    }
}
```

From this, the idea would be to use AJAX and jQuery to:

- Send the (current) selected category to the server, using the "change" event on the dropdown
- Generate and display the new dropdown below the previous one, with the adequate

However, I do not know how to modify the *ProductType* class in order to generate the new *EntityType* field based on the current selected category, then to send back the updated form in order to allow its display by jQuery.

Therefore, any help or advice would be more than welcome in order to make progress in building this dynamic form !

Comment: See if this helps you https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#dynamic-generation-for-submitted-forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly then you need to get child categories for given categories. You can pass it as a option to `ProductType`

```
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use AppBundle\Entity\ProductCategory;
use AppBundle\Repository\ProductCategoryRepository;
 
class ProductType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
            $category = $options['category'];

            $builder->add('productCategory',EntityType::class,array(
                'class'         => 'AppBundle:ProductCategory',
                'query_builder' => function(ProductCategoryRepository $repository) use ($category){
                        return $repository->getRootNodesQueryBuilder($category);
                },
                'label'         => 'product category',
                'choice_label'  => 'name',
                'choice_value'  => 'name',
                'multiple'      => false,
                'expanded'      => false,
                'required'      => true
            ));
    }
 
 
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => Product::class,
            'method' => 'POST',
            'category' => null
        ));
    }
}
```

In **getRootNodesQueryBuilder()** you can parse child categories based upon passed category. In controller (where you receive AJAX request), you can use it like

```
$form = $this->createForm(ProductType::class, $product, [
        'category' => $request->get('category')
]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will go this way. However: I have one issue regarding my controller: how is it possible to detect whether the form has been fully submitted (which is done through AJAX, too), or if only partial data has been sent (i.e. the newly selected category) ? If possible, I would like to use the same controller for both cases.

Comment: I would suggest to not to submit partial data. You can post this field value in ajax data instead and get in request. Thus you wont have to worry about partial or full data. If you really need to check you can just check for some other field if it is in post data

Comment: The problem with posting a single field in ajax to the controller is that the $form->handleRequest($request) throws an error because I guess it is expecting the data for all fields (not only the category sent through ajax). In the case where a single field has been posted, I think I would have not to use the handleRequest method... but in this case I do not know how to update the form since the form is not submitted (and the update in based on the POST_SUBMIT event...).